# How to get the max value of column based on condition between two other columns?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame with five columns:

1. order_id
2. store_id
3. order_timestamp
4. last_snapshot_timestamp
5. current_value

I want to get the previous_value for the order such that max(last_snapshot_timestamp of the store) is less than the order_timestamp. How can I do this?

Example:

| order_id | store_id | order_timestamp | last_snapshot_timestamp | current_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 9 | 50 |
| 2 | 2 | 11 | 10 | 45 |
| 3 | 1 | 15 | 12 | 100 |
| 4 | 2 | 25 | 17 | 35 |
| 5 | 1 | 27 | 17 | 100 |
| 6 | 2 | 29 | 17 | 35 |

For order_id 3 and 5 which have a store_id of 1 will have the correct value of 50 and for order 4 and 6, it will be 45.

Comment: Can you share sample input and the expected output

Comment: @Vaebhav I have added an example.

Comment: Added the answer , do upvote and accept it , if solves with your question

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of is to break it into 4 steps -

- Generate initial DataFrame - `sparkDF`
- Generate `maxAgg` at `store_id` level to get the `MAX(last_snapshot_timestamp)` from your dataset
- Join `maxAgg` with `sparkDF` to fetch the rows with column `current_value`, satisfying the condition - `max_last_snapshot_timestamp < last_snapshot_timestamp` - `immDF`
- Finally join `immDF` with `sparkDF` on `max_last_snapshot_timestamp == last_snapshot_timestamp` to get the `order_id` against it

#### Data Preparation

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
order_id    store_id    order_timestamp last_snapshot_timestamp current_value
1   1   10  9   50
2   2   11  10  45
3   1   15  12  100
4   2   25  17  35
"""),delimiter='\t'
)

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()

+--------+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------+
|order_id|store_id|order_timestamp|last_snapshot_timestamp|current_value|
+--------+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------+
|       1|       1|             10|                      9|           50|
|       2|       2|             11|                     10|           45|
|       3|       1|             15|                     12|          100|
|       4|       2|             25|                     17|           35|
+--------+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

#### Max TimeStamp - Store Id

```
maxAgg = sparkDF.groupBy(['store_id'])\
                .agg(F.max(F.col('last_snapshot_timestamp'))\
                     .alias('max_last_snapshot_timestamp')
                ).select(
                    F.col('store_id').alias('store_id_max_agg')
                    ,F.col('max_last_snapshot_timestamp')
                )

maxAgg.show()

+----------------+---------------------------+
|store_id_max_agg|max_last_snapshot_timestamp|
+----------------+---------------------------+
|               1|                         12|
|               2|                         17|
+----------------+---------------------------+
```

#### Join - sparkDF & maxAggg

```
immDF = sparkDF.join(maxAgg
                      ,(
                            ( sparkDF['store_id'] == maxAgg['store_id_max_agg'] )
                          & ( sparkDF['last_snapshot_timestamp'] < maxAgg['max_last_snapshot_timestamp'] )
                      )
                      ,'inner'
            ).select(
                 sparkDF['store_id'].alias('store_id_imm')
                ,sparkDF['current_value'].alias('previous_current_value')
                ,maxAgg['max_last_snapshot_timestamp']
            )

immDF.show()

+------------+----------------------+---------------------------+
|store_id_imm|previous_current_value|max_last_snapshot_timestamp|
+------------+----------------------+---------------------------+
|           1|                    50|                         12|
|           2|                    45|                         17|
+------------+----------------------+---------------------------+
```

#### Join - sparkDF & immDF

```
finalDF = sparkDF.join(immDF
                ,(
                            ( sparkDF['store_id'] == immDF['store_id_imm'] )
                          & ( sparkDF['last_snapshot_timestamp'] == immDF['max_last_snapshot_timestamp'] )
                )
            ,'inner'
          ).select(
                sparkDF['*']
                ,immDF['previous_current_value']
            )


finalDF.show()

+--------+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------+----------------------+
|order_id|store_id|order_timestamp|last_snapshot_timestamp|current_value|previous_current_value|
+--------+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------+----------------------+
|       4|       2|             25|                     17|           35|                    45|
|       3|       1|             15|                     12|          100|                    50|
+--------+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: I need this at the order_id level. Max timestamp at store id level will not solve it.

Comment: The final join is getting the required information at the order_id level , using the max_last_snapshot_timestamp

Comment: It is not working. I have edited the example. Can you please recheck from your side?